# Why does space "spring back" after mass has passed through it?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime

A comet travelling through space bends the space around it due to its mass.  But after it has passed, the space is no longer curved.  Why does it do this?  Compare for example, the rut left in soft mud after a car wheel drives through it.  The wheel distorts the mud, but the mud remains distorted.  What is the mechanism that causes space to "spring back" into its original shape?

Comment: space time distortion is due to mass and energy distribution. If there is nothing like that there, then why space need to be distorted?

Comment: What do you mean by and why does there need to be a "mechanism"? For analogy, what is the mechanism that "makes the electric field" spring back after a charge has passed through, or the mechanism that makes the "magnetic field spring back" after we shut down the electromagnet?

Comment: The electric field is either present or absent.  Same with a gravity field.  But there isn't a gravity field.  Instead, space and time itself are distorted.  (Unless electric fields also do that conditionally for charge particles.)

Comment: @Jiminion "The electric field is either present or absent" yes and you can say the analogous phrase for space time curvature: "Space time curvature is either present or absent": If the source of the EM is moved; the field changes. If the "source" of the space time curvature moves/changes the space time curvature changes. As ACuriousMind pointed out there is not really a difference here from a "mechanism" point of view.

Comment: So you are saying gravity acts as a magnetic field?  Does a magnetic field also curve space?

Answer (score 5):

You question is backwards.  The Einstein equation $G_{ab}=8\pi T_{ab}$ says that the curvature G is based on the stress energy tensor T.  When the mass moves out of a space, $T$ goes to $0$ and therefore $G$ goes to $0$.  i.e. curvature is gone.

Your analogy with the mud is just one of time of restitution.  Gravity travels at the speed of light, so the restitution to flat space happens very quickly.  However this is not true for mud.  Mud has cohesion and surface tension which limits the speed of restitution to the non-disturbed state.  Convert your mud to a water puddle and the result is that the water will return to the non-disturbed state quickly in comparison to the mud.

Comment: And why does the mud return to its original state?  Could it be due to, um, gravity?  The above really doesn't explain the why.

Comment: The GR equations are ones of potential energy.  When there is no mass or energy in the space i.e. $T=0$, there is no curvature.  The curvature that was there due to the mass, will propagate away as gravitational radiation.

So basically the equations say that the space is no longer curved because there is nothing there to curve it.